# ImageView keeps reloading while scrolling the ListView

Tags: android, android-asynctask, imageview, thumbnails, android-cursoradapter

I have a list that contains an ImageView and a Textview. I'm trying to display video thumbnails in the ImageView. The problem is that when I scroll down the list the ImageView keeps reloading the thumbnails until it gets the correct one. Same thing happens when I scroll back up the list.

I'm using a CursorAdapter and an AsyncTask class. Here's the code:

```
public class VideoAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

public TheAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
    mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(VideoColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
    int path = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(VideoColumns.DATA);

    ViewHolder holder =  (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    holder.thumb.setId(cursor.getPosition());

    holder.title.setText(name);

    GetThumbnail newImg = new GetThumbnail(holder.thumb);
    newImg.execute(cursor.getString(path));
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View view=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_list,parent,false); 
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
    view.setTag(holder);
    return view;
}

    private static class ViewHolder{
    TextView title; 
    ImageView thumb;
    public ViewHolder(View base) {
        title = (TextView)base.findViewById(R.id.text);
        thumb = (ImageView)base.findViewById(R.id.image);
    }
}

    private class GetThumbnail extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>   {

        private ImageView imv;
        private int mPosition;

        public GetThumbnail(ImageView i){
            imv = i;
            mPosition = i.getId();
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            Bitmap bm;
          bm = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(params[0], Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
            return bm;
        }

        @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
           if(result != null && mPosition == imv.getId()){

            imv.setImageBitmap(result);   
           }

            }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your List view Recycle the rows when you scroll up or down It improver the performance of list view. But if you dont want to recycle it you can stop it.